# intellij freezes when starting tomcat OSX

Tags: macos, tomcat, intellij-idea

Has anyone came across the problem where tomcat 7 freezes intellij (11 & 12) for about 2 minutes on OSX - tomcat itself starts up fine (and I can access the webapps before intellij returns).

It does not seems to be a memory thing as i am only user 25% of the heap and when intellij does return, the memory footprint has not changed.

I'm using mountian lion & JDK 1.7.0_05 & can confirm this issue does not happen on Win7 on the same versions of intellij.

Thanks,

Ian.

Comment: Please contact support with a thread dump of the frozen IDEA process: http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-260.

Comment: Many Thanks @CrazyCoder; i'm aware of the formal process but can't believe this is a systemic issue as i'm not doing anything unique (starting tomcat from intellij in osx)- if I get not other suggestions then will raise with jetbrains that includes thread dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and playing, not solves the issue so raising an issue with jetbrians...